# Where should I place compiled source code

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm running a virtual server for development purposes. On this server there are several packages which are compiled from source. I know the source of these packages should be placed in `/usr/src`. But the FHS doesn't say anything about the compiled packages (the exe-files on windows)

My question: where should I place the compiled sources before installing them?

thanks Jeroen

Comment: I try to create source and binary packages in a scratch space, which gets removed after uploading the packages to my Satellite server or custom repository.

Comment: I'm old (very old). My old time tradition is to build in `/usr/local/src/[whatever]`. Typically you download to that dir. You un-tar in that dir and it creates a sub-dir with the name of the program. You cd into that sub-dir and run `configure` et al. and just leave it there in case you need to tweak and recompile. Usually doesn't take a lot of space. Traditionally, `/usr/src` (at least in the BSD world) is politely reserved for core programs. One does not sully it with add-on stuff.

Comment: The FHS **does** state where to place locally compiled from source package. Not sure why people think this is opinion based. Not sure either why you accepted your own answer that state there is no specific location while there is definitely one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

According to the Filesystem Hierachy Standard the source code in /usr/src is only for reference purposes. Moreover, [Note 35](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#FTN.AEN2042) states that source code should not be built within this hierarchy.

Solution: compiled source does not have a specific path in the system hierarchy

Comment: Compiled source definitely has a specific path in the LFHS: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY

Answer (score 1):

If you want the source and binaries to be in a directory not tight to a specific user, a Linux standard location would be `/usr/local/src/<software-name>` and `/usr/local/bin` (see http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY ).

Alternatively, you might also choose `/opt/<software-name>/src` and  `/opt/<software-name>/bin`.